# main redeclared in this block / expected 'package', found 'EOF'

Tags: go, package, program-entry-point

I'm new to go lang and i got this error "main redeclared in this block"

While practicing on Go , I had a folder specified to just practicing and each time I create a new GO file i get this error "main redeclared in this block" , I know i can resolve it by creating a separated folder or a new folder for each file but is there any other solution